# Correct orientation after UIActivityViewController is dismissed

Tags: ios, rotation, orientation, uideviceorientation, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am presenting UIActivityViewController from my controller. I've encountered issues with rotations. After some data sharing option is chosen, let's say "Mail", mail compose view controller is presented. But if I rotate the device and dismiss the mail controller afterwards, my VC is not rotated to the current orientation. I've tried to set up the completion handler for UIActivityViewController as following:

1)

```
[activityViewController setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed){
            [UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation];
        }];
```

or

2)

```
[activityViewController setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed){
        UIInterfaceOrientation currentOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
        [self layoutForInterfaceOrientation:currentOrientation];
    }];
```

The first solution did not help at all. The second solution left the navigation bar unrotated (12 points difference in height).

Please advise how to handle this situation.

Comment: I have more or less the same problem than you...I am going to try to solve this issue and I will let you know...but one advice, develop in Android is less problemtic than iOS

Comment: Thanks for pointing/commenting to this question... So, I've recalled to post my own researches, check it out below. Probably it will help you as well, at least I hope so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved the issue. First of all, I should say that my VC is always rotated to portrait after MailComposeVC is dismissed regardless of the current device orientation and its state before showing a mail...
And the only VC method that gets called during auto rotation when MailComposeVC is on screen is `viewWillLayoutSubviews/viewDidLayoutSubviews`. (`willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` is not called!)
So, I reset the navigation bar to recover its height and call my custom layout method if my VC is invisible, like that:

```
(void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    // HACK: forcing the bars to refresh themselves - this helps to get the shorter version when switching to landscape and the taller one when going back!!!
    if (amIhidden) { 
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
        UIInterfaceOrientation currentOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
        [self layoutForInterfaceOrientation:currentOrientation];
    }
}
```

`amIhidden BOOL` is set when presenting MailComposeViewController, as following:

```
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
                                                        initWithActivityItems:@[self]
                                                        applicationActivities:nil];
amIhidden = YES;
[activityViewController setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed){
        amIhidden = NO;
}];
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Hope, my solution will help to somebody else!

Answer (score 0):

If the accepted solution didn't work for you ( like me ) I have answered similar question which is easy and clean. [Objective c - UIActivityViewController orientation mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978432/objective-c-uiactivityviewcontroller-orientation-mode/25025492#25025492)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution in Swift 3. But I think it should also work in Objective-C.

In `AppDelegate` function `application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask`, return the right orientation for specific view controller.

**The tricky part is that you have to dig out the view controller which you want the orientation to be based on.** Like in my case, when `UIActivityViewController` is presented, `window?.currentViewController()` and `window?.topMostController()` are both `UIActivityViewController`. Because I use `UIActivityViewController` in other places, I can't use it as the clue. Then I checked `window?.currentViewController()?.presentingViewController` and found it is a `UINavigationController`. Since I know the view controller I wanna base on is the top view controller of that `UINavigationController`, my solution is as following:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

    if window?.currentViewController() is MyLandscapeViewController{
        return [UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscapeLeft, UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscapeRight]
    }

    if let presenting = window?.currentViewController()?.presentingViewController{
        if let nav = presenting as? UINavigationController{
            if nav.topViewController is MyLandscapeViewController{
                return [UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscapeLeft, UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscapeRight]
            }
        }
    }

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait;
}
```

With this code, the screen no longer rotate to portrait but stay in landscape after a sharing option is chosen when MyLandscapeViewController is presented.