# Force UIActivityViewController to display in Landscape Mode

Tags: ios, ios8, landscape, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am looking for a way to force the the `UIActivityViewController` to display in landscape mode. My app is exclusively portrait except for a image VC that pushes landscape images to be full screen and from here I want the user to be able to launch the `UIActivityViewController` in landscape (like below)... however, it always launches in Portrait mode currently.

[image: Landscape Mode]

I have `shouldAutoRotate` set to `NO` because I need to custom handle how I move certain pieces of the UI rotate. I currently have the `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` set to `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait` and have tried removing it but it does not seem to have an impact. Ideally, I would like to keep it set to `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait` for this view.

I tried setting the status bar (thinking that is what it was using to identify what orientation to launch in) but that did not work either (code below). The status bar is hidden in this VC.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
```

Bounty time to help me launch this menu in landscape mode as well as the corresponding user selection (i.e. if they select 'Message' for it to launch in landscape mode as well).

Here are the basics of the code to recreate what I am seeing

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(launchShareMenu)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
}

-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden{

return YES;
}


-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {

return NO;
}


- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {

return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}




- (void) launchShareMenu {

NSString *stringToShare = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Share Me"];
UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[stringToShare] applicationActivities:nil];

NSArray *excludedActivities = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
                                UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
                                UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
                                UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                                UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                                UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                                UIActivityTypePostToVimeo,
                                UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo];

controller.excludedActivityTypes = excludedActivities;

//Present controller
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28056399/present-uiactivityviewcontroller-in-landscape-mode

Comment: Hi Chase, have you tried what is mentioned in this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978432/objective-c-uiactivityviewcontroller-orientation-mode

Comment: @JasperPol - I have looked at that question but unfortunately it does not work in my situation. I want to push the UiActivity controller in landscape mode on a VC where auto-rotation is turned off.

Comment: Can you create a sample code and share which replicates the issue? In case you haven't solved it yet.

Comment: @bllakjakk -- I added the basics to the post that you can simple cut and paste into an empty project to see what I am seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the `viewDidLoad()` of viewcontroller

```
let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft.rawValue
UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
```

Answer (score 0):

The picture you shared is the landscape view of uiactivityviewcontroller. you can't force it to show in landscape.